# Joining two tables on multiple different columns with different numbers of rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

temp has 7027 rows with the schema shown below

```
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ip          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | month       | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | day         | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | hour        | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | totcount    | bigint(21)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and temp1 has 4972 rows again with the schema shown below

```
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ip          | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | month       | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | day         | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | hour        | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | compcount   | bigint(21)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I am trying to do is attach the column compcount from temp1 to the data in temp, with either a 0 or a null value anywhere where there isn't a value for compcount. All of the ip, month, day, hour combinations that exist in temp1 also exist in temp but the opposite is not true.

As an example, if I have temp as follows:

```
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
    | ip             | month | day  | hour | totcount |
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   17 |    0 |      215 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   18 |    1 |      490 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   19 |    0 |      749 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   20 |    0 |      471 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   21 |   15 |      330 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   22 |   15 |       45 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   23 |   14 |      214 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     2 |   25 |    1 |       13 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   17 |   21 |       58 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   18 |   22 |       70 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   20 |   22 |       89 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   21 |   11 |       67 |
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
```

and temp1:

```
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
    | ip             | month | day  | hour | compcount|
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   17 |    0 |      100 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   18 |    1 |      176 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   21 |   15 |      182 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   22 |   15 |       36 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   23 |   14 |      198 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   17 |   21 |       46 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   18 |   22 |       53 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   20 |   22 |       27 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   21 |   11 |       61 |
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+
```

then I would like the resulting table to be:

```
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+----------+
    | ip             | month | day  | hour | totcount |compcount |
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+----------+
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   17 |    0 |      215 |      100 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   18 |    1 |      490 |      176 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   19 |    0 |      749 |        0 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   20 |    0 |      471 |        0 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   21 |   15 |      330 |      182 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   22 |   15 |       45 |       36 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     1 |   23 |   14 |      214 |      198 |
    | 0.0.0.0        |     2 |   25 |    1 |       13 |        0 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   17 |   21 |       58 |       46 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   18 |   22 |       70 |       53 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   20 |   22 |       89 |       27 |
    | 1.1.1.1        |     1 |   21 |   11 |       67 |       61 | 
    +----------------+-------+------+------+----------+----------+
```

I tried the query

```
    select temp.ip, temp.month, temp.day, temp.hour, temp.totcount,
    temp1.compcount from temp1 left outer join temp on
    temp.ip=temp1.ip and temp.month=temp1.month and
    temp.day=temp1.day and temp.hour=temp1.hour order by ip;
```

but it only returned 4972 rows. How do I construct a query so that it returns what I'm looking for?

Comment: What happens if you switch to just an "outer join" or a "right join"? Trying to confirm that the difference isn't unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `LEFT JOIN`, the first table should be the one that has all the rows, and the second table is the one that might not have matches.

So change the order of the tables, or use `RIGHT JOIN`.

```
select temp.ip, temp.month, temp.day, temp.hour, temp.totcount,
        temp1.compcount 
from temp 
left outer join temp1 on
    temp.ip=temp1.ip and temp.month=temp1.month and
    temp.day=temp1.day and temp.hour=temp1.hour 
order by ip, month, day, hour;
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/VXIB53126)

And if you want `0` instead of `NULL` in the results, use `IFNULL(temp1.compcount, 0) AS compcount`

Comment: I changed it and the query is now taking quite a long time to run. I ran the EXPLAIN command and the type is listed as ALL and the values for "possible_keys", "key", and "key_len" are all NULL. Is there a way to utilize keys here to speed this up?

Comment: Add a composite index on `(ip, month, day, hour)` (or at least some subset of this) to both tables.